# C# LINQ converting a query to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, dictionary, windows-7

A C# converting a query to dictionary:

```
public class myClass
{
    public int my_id;
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>> myDict;
}

Dictionary<string, myClass> dataDict;

Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, myClass>> query = (from happen in dataDict 
                     group happen by happen.Value.my_id into g 
                     select g).ToDictionary( ?? );
```

I do not know what I should put in ( ?? ).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = (from happen in dataDict
            group happen by happen.Value.my_id into g select g)
           .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
```

Comment: what if public Dictionary<string, string[]> myDict ? it will be g => g.Key, g => g.value ? thanks !